# How do I assign a string to $_SESSION?

Tags: php, session, session-variables

**I've fixed this, thank you everyone for your help!**

The value of $_SESSION["nama_pengguna"] and $_SESSION["kata_laluan"] remains NULL and doesn't change to $nama_pengguna and $kata_laluan after passing all 3 if statements.

when:

- $_POST is not NULL
- $_POST["daftar"] is not NULL
- $result is not NULL

value I get:

- $_SESSION["nama_pengguna"] => NULL
- $_SESSION["kata_laluan"] => NULL

expected value:

- $_SESSION["nama_pengguna"] => $nama_pengguna
- $_SESSION["kata_laluan"] => $kata_laluan

extra information:

- $_SESSION["login"] works fine

  - when passes all if statements, $_SESSION["login"] => true
  - when doesn't pass all if statements, $_SESSION["login"] => false
  - I expected $_SESSION["nama_pengguna"] and $_SESSION["kata_laluan"] to copy this behaviour but it doesn't.
- I've tried removing the first appearance of
  $_SESSION["nama_pengguna"] and $_SESSION["kata_laluan"], but those
  two variables stopped existing once I did that.

snippet from login.php

```php
<?php
    session_start();
    include("sambungan.php");
    $_SESSION["login"] = false;
    $_SESSION["nama_pengguna"] = NULL; #Problem
    $_SESSION["kata_laluan"] = NULL;  #Problem

    if (!empty($_POST) && !empty($_POST["nama_pengguna"]) && !empty($_POST["kata_laluan"])) {
        $nama_pengguna = $_POST["nama_pengguna"];
        $kata_laluan = $_POST["kata_laluan"];
    
        if (isset($_POST["daftar"])) {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO urusetia (nama_pengguna,kata_laluan) VALUES ('$nama_pengguna','$kata_laluan')";
            $result = mysqli_query($sambungan,$sql);
            if ($result) {
                $_SESSION["login"] = true;
                $_SESSION["nama_pengguna"] = $nama_pengguna; #Problem
                $_SESSION["kata_laluan"] = $kata_laluan; #Problem

                $_POST = array();
                header("Location:./hakim.php");
                die();
            }
        }
    ...
```

snippet from login.php

```html
...
        <form action="login.php" method="post">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Nama Pengguna</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="nama_pengguna" autocomplete="off" placeholder="max 30 characters" required></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Kata Laluan</td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="kata_laluan" autocomplete="off" placeholder="max 15 characters" required></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" name="daftar" value="Daftar">
            <input type="submit" name="log_masuk" value="Log Masuk">
        </form>
...
```

echo-ing all the $_SESSION variables

[image: echo-ing all the $_SESSION variables]

Comment: I don't understand the question. explain it clearly please.

Comment: @HamidMoladoust I'm so sorry!! I've just made some edits, please tell me if any adjustments should be made, thank you for the feedback.

Comment: stop doing thinks manually and start using a php framework (laravel)

Comment: @giò I have to do things manually because this is for a school project

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? `if ($_POST)`  won't check whether there are any values in the POST array. Also, your `INSERT` query is highly vunlerable for SQL injection - have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

Comment: @NicoHaase I just want $nama_pengguna and $kata_laluan to be $_SESSION variables when the 3 conditions above are met so I can use them in other pages.

Comment: And what have you tried to achieve that? Did you check whether the line where you set these two session variables is properly executed?

Comment: @NicoHaase I have tried checking the variables in another page, and the value I get is NULL. the login session variable changes to true which means all the if statements were true, but those two variables don't change (which is the problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You checked just $_POST in first condition.
it is good practice to check if $_POST["nama_pengguna"] and $_POST["kata_laluan"] is not empty too. (isset is not enough):

```
...
if ($_POST && !empty($_POST["nama_pengguna"]) && !empty($_POST["kata_laluan"])) {
    // not you can be sure both of that data is exist and have some data.
    $nama_pengguna = $_POST["nama_pengguna"];
    $kata_laluan = $_POST["kata_laluan"];

    ....
} else {
  // return some error because of being empty needed data.
}
```

but you maybe you have to add an "else" to you condition for return some errors because the data does not have enough data we need.

Comment: I have changed my code to the above, but it still doesn't fix the main issue

Comment: please log the $_POST array before with something like print_r($_POST);exit; do you get vars: nama_pengguna and kata_laluan?